# How can random array access be considered $O(1)$ if bits must be stored in space and light travels at finite speed?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

Bits are usually stored linearly in space. We can say, thus, that the length of a memory chip, for example, is linearly proportional to the number of bits it can hold. Since signals must travel at finite speed in our universe, the time it takes to read the last element an array will always be proportional to the length of the array. Am I missing something?

Comment: This assumes that memory is stored on a chip in a linear fashion.  But most likely, memory is stored on a chip in a tree-like fashion where access to any byte on the chip takes the same amount of time.

Comment: @JS1 But some connections in the memory chip are surely longer than others, so there are areas of memory where a signal takes physically longer to reach than others.

Comment: @David Richerby Even if that were true, memory accesses are gated by a clock, so an access can only take an integral number of clock cycles.  I'm reasonably sure that for a single memory chip, every byte on the chip takes the same number of cycles to read.

Answer (score 4):

When we talk about "running time" of algorithms, we don't mean literally time in seconds but number of operations in some abstracted machine model. In such a model, accessing a memory cell is taken to be a single operation, taking unit time.

Note that this is hiding much more significant details of real computers than the speed of light across a chip.  Whether or not the required data is in the cache will have a much more significant effect than any consideration based on the speed of light.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it in terms of the number of statements that need to be executed to perform what you want.

The growth factor of the function f(n) is O(n) if the runtime increases linearly with the size of the input. If you are iterating through an entire list, going through 100,000,000,000,000 should time a proportionally longer time than iterating through 100 elements. Obviously, you are executing the (same) statement many more times, so it takes more time to process.

The growth factor of the function f(n) of accessing an element in an array doesn't depend on the size of the input (its a simple access to an offset of an address), so its constant O(1). Accessing the ith element of an array of 100,000,000,000 elements shouldn't take any appreciable more time then accessing the ith element of an array of 100 elements. In both cases, you end up with "go to to my address + i and return the value there". One statement.